# AngularJS doesn't render view specified in $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

myApp.config(function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
});

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("", {
            templateUrl: "Views/Employee/Employees.html",
            controller: "EmployeesController"
        }).otherwise({ redirectTo: 'Views/Employee/Employees' });
});
```

It routes the URL mentioned in otherwise, not the URL mentioned in the .when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root route of your Angular app will be `"/"`, not `""`.

Then, `redirectTo` takes as value a route defined in your route provider.

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "Views/Employee/Employees.html",
            controller: "EmployeesController"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```